# How to manage the same script on many computers at once?

Tags: linux, script

I am a student doing research in multi-agent systems. I have a network of 4 raspberry pi cameras that I am using to do some vision processing and combining the results using some algorithms developed as part of my research. The idea is that I make all the cameras identical so I can add/subtract/substitute nodes as needed. I would like to write a python script on my local (linux) computer, upload it, and be able to start and stop it on all my nodes at once. Is there a program out there that will let me do that? I haven't found one so far. If not, I guess I will be writing one.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible is an IT automation tool that can do remote execution and orchestration. You can use the script module for your use case.